# Azure web app - Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

Tags: php, linux, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a PHP app on the azure web app(Linus and PHP7.2). All the code copied to the root directory. When I trying to access the site I am getting "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

How can I add extensions in Azure web app Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate mysql/mssql extension in azure.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/windows-server-azure-pack/dn457758(v%3Dtechnet.10)

OR

in Azure Web app.
open-up your webssh and execute the following commands.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php7.2-mysql
```

Comment: We are using LINUX web app with PHP7.2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried with the command but failed with error :    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-mysql'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-mysql'

Comment: try executing this command before executing those two.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

Comment: Executed that command but again some error "-bash: add-apt-repository: command not found"